# How do you integrate jekyll with twitter bootstrap?

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, jekyll

I need to build a design site for my company and I'm going to use jekyll to create a static site. I want to integrate twitter bootstrap and if possible bootstrap themes(or customize my own). I've been looking around the web and cant find anything clearly outlining how to do this.

Comment: How about using something like https://github.com/dbtek/jekyll-bootstrap-3 ?